# Having trouble closing a 'for' loops using an array

Tags: c, loops, break

The problem I seem to be having with my code is that the for loop doesn't seem to break at the correct time. The idea is that when all the values inside the array are greater than zero the for loop breaks. The problem is that the break does not occur. Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int randomInt(int max)
 {
  return (random(2)%max);
 }

main()
 {
  int i,k=0,j;
  int position=1,r=1; /*Position indicates the position of the particle
                        and r represents where the particle will move
                        next*/ 
  int seed,L=10,M=20;/*L is the number of sites and M is the number of hops*/
  float n,sum=0;
  float average;

  int frequency[M]; 
  for(i=0;i<(M);i++)
   {
    frequency[i]=0;
   }
  //setup the random seed generator
  printf("\nEnter your value of seed\n");
  scanf("%d",&seed);
  srandom(seed); 

  for(i=0;i<M;i++) //This loops around the total number of loops.
   {

      printf("\nThe particle is at position %d\n",position);
      n=randomInt(2);/*This chooses either the numbers 0 or 1 randomly */

      frequency[position]=frequency[position]+1;
      printf("This position has been visited %d times\n",frequency[position]);

      sum=sum+frequency[position];

      /*Below represents the conditions which will determine the movement
        of the particle*/              
        if(n==0)
         {
           r=1;
         }
        if(n==1)
         {
           r=-1;
         }
        position = position + r;
        if(position==0)
         {
          position=L;
         }

        if(position==L+1)
         {
          position=1;
         }

        //This 'for' loop below is used to check if all the sites have been visited.

        for(j=0;j<(L-1);j++) 
         {
          if(frequency[j]==0)
           {
            k++;
           }  
         }

        if(k==0)
         {
          break;
         }
        if(k!=0)
         {
          k=0;
         }

      }
    printf("\nThe particle hopped %d times when it visited every site\n",i);

    printf("\nThe total frequency of hops is %.lf\n",sum);
    average=sum/i;
    printf("\nAverage number of hops made when all the sites have been visited %.2lf\n",average);
}
```

Comment: It seems that `n` is always `0`. It is declared as `float` and you are assigning `int` value to it.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're only exiting the inner, nested `for` loop. The best way to `break` from both, is to set some `bool` flag, set it to `true` while breaking from the inner loop, and then check the condition in the outer:

```
bool flag = false;
```

then in the inner:

```
flag = true;
break;
```

and right after that in the outer:

```
if(flag) break;
```

Edit:

IF I misunderstood, and you only want to break from the inner, the reason it happens might be also that you don't reset your `k` to zero after every bigger iteration, so if the next array is zeros only, `k` still has the old value and never stays `0` in the end.